# twilio untrusted root ssl certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, twilio, twilio-php

twilio newbie here.  Although I was able to successfully send a test sms message, this was done only by turning the certificate check to false.  I'm on a hosted server.  This is what my hosted provider said:

Twilio is doing a couple of things wrong.  They're sending a root certificate in their certificate chain, which they shouldn't do, and the root they're sending is an old Thawte root from 1996 which is no longer trusted because it was signed by a 1024 bit key, which is now considered insecure.  Because they're sending this untrusted root, you get the self-signed certificate exception, which is exactly what should happen in this case.
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=api.twilio.com

Again, this is way over my head.  Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Sorry you got hit with the untrusted root SSL error. You can read a bit of the cause [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/203) but the short version is we've removed the pinned certificate chain from our library and as a result the PHP installation on your server needs to have access to a recent bundle of CA certificates that we can verify against.

[This blog post](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/) is the best walkthrough I've found on how to resolve this error. Hope that helps get you sorted!

Comment: Ricky, thanks for the response.  I'm still confused though. The SSL checker does state that the certificate is older.  Why doesn't Twilio just fix this and use a trusted root?                                                                                                               In the meantime, my host provider will not make any changes to the server.  Can you give a little bit more description on what I can do? The blog is not clear enough for me to follow.

Comment: Cherrie, if you can't make changes to the host it sounds like we may need to dig a bit deeper to get this resolved. Want to drop us an e-mail to help@twilio.com and we can work to help get this working?

Comment: Created ticket via Twilio online form.  It would be helpful if there were a very simple write-up for this kind of situation where host provider will not make changes to server.

Comment: Very good feedback. Appreciate your patience in getting this worked out. You mind sharing who you're hosting with? I'm going to investigate a bit more on my end as well.

Comment: I sent another email to help@twilio and referenced this conversation.  I also mentioned my host provider.  Hopefully, y'all respond soon.

Comment: Received instructions from twilio help desk.  They suggested I change the certificate check line from "true" to "0" per this link: [link](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html))  Again, I don't really understand but test sms texts do go through